# How to find the number of observations needed to discard the null hypothesis with a given probability when the sample size is low?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, hypothesis-testing

So I have the following values:

$X_i ~ N(\mu=9.6, \sigma=1.6)$

Samples = 8.4, 7.8, 10.3, 8.7, 10.7, 10.0, 8.8, 12.1

X̄ = 9.6

α = 0.05

I should also mentioned that I have the following hypothesis test:

$H_0: μ \le 8$

$H_1: μ > 8$

I want to find the number of observations needed in my sample so that the probability of discarding the null hypothesis is 0.99.

All of the examples I find online use a Z-table. My problem is however, since the number of samples < 30, shouldn't a T-table be used? But how can you find n with a T-table when the T value depends on n. If I wanted to do some other calculations with with Y, say a hypothesis test to find out if the mean is larger than a given number, I would most definitely use a T-distribution, right? But should I just a Z-table for this specific use-case?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Is $\bar X$ your notation for the mean of observations $Y?$ Is 1.6 the mean or the SD of $Y?$  You begin with $n = 8$ observations, and then ask what $n$ is needed for a certain rejection probability. What is the connection?

Comment: X̄ is the mean of the samples I included in the question. 1.6 Is the SD. So, the reason I included the samples is that I used them when doing the earlier calculations that I mentioned in the question. But this is not really relevant to the question, so I could remove it. I am looking for the n needed such that the power of the test 0.99. My trouble is that all of the examples I find online use the Z-table to find critical values, but can I do this when a T-table would normally be used for calculations since n<30

Comment: OK, now we're converging toward an answerable question. One of the requirements for a power computation is to know what alternative you have in mind. Is that 9.6?

Comment: Yes, that is the true mean of the distribution. Sorry that my question was poorly phrased. The main issue was that I was just confused by how I started this task by using a T-table to find critical values for my first hypothesis test, which was mainly about showing that the mean is most likely above 8. Then I was asked to find the number of samples needed in to get a power value of 0.99, which didn't seem possible using a T-distribution. But as I understand it know, the samples are unrelated to this second calculation, which makes perfect sense. So I should just use a Z-table.

Comment: To avoid confusion, I edited your Question for formatting and included that $\sigma = 1.6$ in the notation for the normal distribution. Suggest you remove misleading data. // As for the last paragraph, by now I suppose you've figured out this is a z-test because we're assuming $\sigma=1.6$ is known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In testing $H_0: \mu \le 8$ against $H_a: \mu > 8$ based on normal data with $\sigma = 1.6,$ are you asking what $n$ is necessary to give power .99 against the specific alternative value $\mu_a = 9.6?$ That is, the power against an
alternative that is one SD away from the hypothetical mean $\mu_0 = 8?$

If so, here are results from
Minitab statistical software:

```
Power and Sample Size 

1-Sample Z Test

Testing mean = null (versus > null)
Calculating power for mean = null + difference
α = 0.05  Assumed standard deviation = 1.6


            Sample  Target
Difference    Size   Power  Actual Power
       1.6      16    0.99      0.990742
```

In such circumstances, power is a *function* of the distance $\delta = \mu_a - \mu_0.$
Here is Minitab's power curve. It shows increasing power for $n = 16$ as $\delta$ increases; power reaches about .99 for $\delta = 1.6.$

[image]

To solve this without specialized software, it might help to
find the 'Acceptance region' in terms of the sample mean of $n$ observations
when $\mu_0 = 8,\, \alpha = .05,$ and $\sigma = 1.6.$ Then standardize
the endpoints of that interval in terms of $\mu = 9.6,$ find the 
the probability of the interval, subtract from 1 to get an expression for the probability
of the 'rejection' region, and solve for $n.$

*Note:* The statistics text by Ott and Longnecker ('Key Formulas List' at the end of Chapter 5) reduces this process to an equation for $n:$

$$n = \frac{\sigma^2}{\delta^2}(z_\alpha  + z_\beta)^2,$$
where $z_\alpha$ cuts 5% of the probability from the upper tail of a standard normal
distribution (for a test a level $\alpha$ and $z_\beta$ cuts
1% (fort Type II error 1% and power 99%). In your case,  $z_\alpha  = 1.645,\,
z_\beta = 2.326,$  and $n = 15.77,$ which Minitab rounds up to 16.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That helped a lot! I managed to solve it now. The correct answer is 16, but your software solotuion really helped. You just used a SD of 1.4

Comment: Just now fixed my typo using Minitab, and posted corrected results. Caught the mistake because the formula from Ott's book didn't match my result from Minitab.

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether your test was designed under the assumption that the variance is known or unknown. If unknown you need to use $T$ to find the rejection region for $\alpha =0.05$. If known (and presumably $1.6$) then you should use Z.

Either way, once you have the rejection region, no further use of the T distribution is necessary. You need to calculate the probability that the sample mean, which has distribution $N(9.6,1.6/n)$, falls in the rejection region, and this only requires the normal distribution.

Comment: The question is not clear. But under any interpretation, I'm not sure this answer is useful. //  in order to find the sample size necessary for a **t test** to have a certain power, one needs to use the non-central t distribution.

Comment: I am looking for the n needed such that the power of the test 0.99. My trouble is that all of the examples I find online use the Z-table to find critical values, but can I do this when a T-table would normally be used for calculations since n<30. So basically my question could be boiled down to, can I use a Z-table to find these critical values and calculate the power using the normal methods I find online, or will I have to use another method using a T-table?

Comment: @BruceET I'm guessing we're in "known variance" case (and you raise a good point that it seems numerically like $1.6$ is the std dev, not the variance as I've assumed). We are told the "true" distribution for the purposes of the power calculation and that includes the variance here. I agree it would be strange (and possibly incoherent) to consider the variance unknown for the first part and known for the second. Though power calculations are always under an assumption about effect size, its conceivable an assumption about variance might be relevant.

Comment: @Martin Bruce raises a good point that we don't know quite what to make of your eight or so samples. They don't seem relevant. My guess would be that we're under the assumption of normal with known variance and just use Z tables.